# How to decode "\u002522\u00253A etc" In C#

Tags: c#, encoding

I'm not familiar with this encoding, what is it and how do I decode it in C#?

\u00257B\u002522target_id\u002522\u00253A\u002522p\u00257C29681347\u002522\u00252C+\u002522prop_id\u002522\u00253A\u0025222\u002522\u00252C+\u002522tid\u002522\u00253A\u0025221316132877\u002522\u00252C+\u002522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it's a C# string literal like this

```
string text = "\u00257B\u002522target_id\u002522\u00253A\u002522p...";
```

then you don't need to decode it at all. It's just a string literal that happens to contain an escape code.

> The escape code \udddd (where dddd is a four-digit number) represents the Unicode character U+dddd. Eight-digit Unicode escape codes are also recognized: \Udddddddd.

So `\u0025` represents the character `%`.

If you display the string, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

you get the following output:

```
%7B%22target_id%22%3A%22p...
```

---

The output looks like an URL encoded string. You can decode it using the [Uri.UnescapeDataString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx):

```
string decoded = Uri.UnescapeDataString(text);
// decoded == "{\"target_id\":\"p..."
```

If you display the decoded string

```
Console.WriteLine(decoded);
```

you get the following output:

```
{"target_id":"p...
```

Comment: Thanks. It isn't actually a C# string. It is some JSON contained in some javascript that I've read in so it actually looks like this "\\u00257B" and C# doesn't recognize the escaped unicode char. How would you recommend I get around this?

Comment: So it's url-encoded JSON embedded in JSON? Nice... I'd recommend you use a JSON library to parse the JSON and get an unescaped string. Then url-decode it and use the JSON library to parse the url-decoded unescaped string.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode() on that string to get

```
  {"target_id":"p|29681347", "prop_id":"2", "tid":"1316132877", "
```

Clearly it is a fragment of the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

That's a unicode representation for a keyvalue pair list:

{"target_id":"p|29681347",+"prop_id":"2",+"tid":"1316132877",+"

You can decode it with the common System.Text.Encoding.Unicode classes.