# Decoding u002522, u002522 and a lot of backslash

Tags: c#, utf-8, decode, urldecode

I am using WebClient to fetch som web requests:

```
public static string PostHttp(string url, Dictionary<string, string> headers, Dictionary<string, string> postParams)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {                
        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                client.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }

        var reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

        if (postParams != null)
        {
            foreach (var param in postParams)
            {
                reqparm.Add(param.Key, param.Value);
            }
        }


        byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", reqparm);
        return  Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
    }
}
```

And I get something like following in Visual Studio:

```
\\\"see_more_cards_id\\\",\\\"href\\\":\\\"\\\\\\/page_content_list_view\\\\\\/more\\\\\\/?page_id=200168320060101&start_cursor=\\\\u00257B\\\\u002522timeline_cursor\\\\u002522\\\
```

In post man it looks better here I would just be able to do an url decode:

```
\"see_more_cards_id\",\"href\":\"\\\/page_content_list_view\\\/more\\\/?page_id=200168320060101&start_cursor=\%7B\%22timeline_cursor\%22\%3
```

In Chrome debugger its like following:

```
\"see_more_cards_id\",\"href\":\"\\\/page_content_list_view\\\/more\\\/?page_id=200168320060101&start_cursor=\\u00257B\\u002522timeline_cursor\\u002522\\u00253A\\u002522timeline_unit\\
```

What I am looking for is a decoded versions like:

```
"see_more_cards_id","href":\"/page_content_list_view/more/?page_id=200168320060101&start_cursor={"timeline_cursor":""timeline_unit:timeline_unit: 1:00000000001564446283:04611686018427387904:091:00000000001564446283:04611686018`427387904:09
```

I tried searching for decoding characters like u002522 but there is only a very limited information. I found following post that suggested using Uri.UnescapeDataString but this didnt decode the chars.

[Decode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504908/how-to-decode-u002522-u00253a-etc-in-c-sharp)

Comment: All of strings are valid JSON according to standardб VS adds additional slashes for proper handling of quotes

Comment: vs always adds slashes so if you had \" in a string it would always be \\\" ..

Comment: Just funny my web request, crome developer tool and postman all give different results. Do you anything about u002552 encodings? Is it a none standard encoding? There is very limited info. I wonder how Postman decodes it. looks like they get some uri encodings instead.

Comment: Please show the Content-Type response header and/or API documentation. It says `application/json`, right?

Comment: If the response is an HTTP status code and/or JSON, why does `PostHttp` return a `String`? What is the caller going to do with it? Why does it matter how a debugger displays it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\\\\u002522
```

There are many layers here.

First, there is \ escaping for \. (This one is probably just a debugger trying to be helpful.) So,

```
\\u002522
```

Then there is \ escaping for \. So,

```
\u002522
```

Then there is \u escaping for a UTF-16 code unit

```
%22
```

Then there is %-encoding (aka URL-encoding) of bytes, presumably for UTF-8 code units

```
"
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by making my own decoding with a simple replace.